# Ms Graph API Onedrive copy returning generalException

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api, onedrive, azure-ad-graph-api

I have developped a webapp using Ms Graph API to copy files from sharepoint libraries to other sharepoint libraries (all online).

I call the Graph API copy like this:

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/SrcDriveID/items/*SrcDriveItem*/copy?@microsoft.graph.conflictBehavior=replace

{ "parentReference" :  { "driveId": "*DestDriveID*",  "id": "*DestParentDriveItem*" },  "@microsoft.graph.conflictBehavior":"replace" } }
```

I receive the following error:

```
<Internal Server Error> <{"error": {"code": "generalException","message": "An unspecified error has occurred.","innerError": {"request-id": "0623069a-7071-47f9-be92-48d58902f300","date": "2020-05-06T21:11:07"}}}>
```

The webapp is using delegated permissions and only work accounts. The grants given to this app for Graph API are:

- Directory.read.all
- File.ReadWrite
- Sites.Read.All
- User.Read
- File.ReadWrite.All

The issue is systematic on my production environment. I don't have it on my dev environment although the permissions are the same. The users triggering the webapp (and the related bearer key) have Read / Write access on the source and the destination sharepoint libraries. On the destination they are members and not owners.

Any help is welcome !

Thanks in advance

**UPDATE**:
Adding the .NET C# Code:

```
        StringBuilder jsonData = new StringBuilder("{ \"parentReference\" :  { \"driveId\": \"" + DestDriveID + "\",  \"id\": \"" + DestParentDriveItem + "\" },  \"@microsoft.graph.conflictBehavior\":\"replace\" } }");

        String restCallUrl;

        if (overwrite)
        {
            restCallUrl = _baseUri + "drives/" + SrcDriveID + "/items/" + SrcDriveItem + "/copy?@microsoft.graph.conflictBehavior=replace";
        }
        else
        {
            restCallUrl = _baseUri + "drives/" + SrcDriveID + "/items/" + SrcDriveItem + "/copy";
        }


        HttpClient apiCallClient = new HttpClient();

        HttpRequestMessage apiRequest = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, restCallUrl);
        apiRequest.Headers.Accept.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
        HttpContent addAttachmentBody = new StringContent(jsonData.ToString(), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
        apiRequest.Content = addAttachmentBody;

        apiRequest.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + _accessToken);

        HttpResponseMessage apiCallResponse = await apiCallClient.SendAsync(apiRequest);



        if (apiCallResponse.StatusCode != System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Accepted)
        {
            String requestResponse = await apiCallResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            _mylog.Warning("Copy -<" + apiCallResponse.ReasonPhrase + "> <" + requestResponse + ">");
            throw new DllNotFoundException();
        }
```

**UPDATE**
I realized that the jsonData was not well balanced. I correct with the following:

```
StringBuilder jsonData = new StringBuilder("{ \"parentReference\" :  { \"driveId\": \"" + DestDriveID + "\",  \"id\": \"" + DestParentDriveItem + "\" },  \"@microsoft.graph.conflictBehavior\":\"replace\",  \"name \":  \"" + DstFileName + "\"  }");
```

or

```
StringBuilder jsonData = new StringBuilder("{ \"parentReference\" :  { \"driveId\": \"" + DestDriveID + "\",  \"id\": \"" + DestParentDriveItem + "\" },  \"@microsoft.graph.conflictBehavior\":\"replace\" }");
```

both are failing with the same error.

The last one gave me:

```
Copy -<Internal Server Error> <{"error": {"code": "generalException","message": "An unspecified error has occurred.","innerError": {"request-id": "ebf30e17-b4be-4994-bf86-bc3b86834d12","date": "2020-05-09T07:30:42"}}}>
```

**UPDATE**:
I have done the exact same action on Graph explorer and it did work

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/b!fffffffffqv/items/01GEGKyyyyyyuuHR/copy?@microsoft.graph.conflictBehavior=replace
{ "driveId": "b!yyyyy",  "id": "uuuuuu" },  "@microsoft.graph.conflictBehavior":"replace" }
```

It does work with Graph API explorer as soon as File.ReadWrite and Files.ReadWrite.All are set. I'll double check that they are applied on my webapp.
**UPDATE**
Files.ReadWrite.All  permission is set to application while delegated is expected. Awaiting the change.
**UPDATE** Issue fixed by above change

Comment: Can you provide complete error information?

Comment: Hello @CarlZhao, I'm happy to give anything related to the issue but here I don't see much what I could give. Below the code. Maybe I missed something. 

 HttpResponseMessage apiCallResponse = await apiCallClient.SendAsync(apiRequest);

 if (apiCallResponse.StatusCode != System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Accepted)
{
                String requestResponse = await apiCallResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

                _mylog.Warning("Copy -<" + apiCallResponse.ReasonPhrase + "> <" + requestResponse + ">");
                throw new DllNotFoundException(); }

Answer (score 0):

File.readwrite.all permission was set as application while delegated was expected.